# Multiple contact form

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, forms, contact-us, contact-form

I create few contacts forms in Magento for example I have `Contact1.phtml / Contact2.phtml / Contact3.phtml` is there any way to setup transnational email for each contact form?

Right now I use only one transactional email for all with if statement, But I see a lot of blank spaces where the field not exist and is very ugly. The email now is look like this:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad to meet you with this issue because i was struggling with same issue just 4 months ago.

You created multiple contact forms separately right?  Did you insert these contact forms to `design` folder and is it displayed on your front website? Then, it's time to specify transnational email on each contact form.

I think you might copy the original contact form to make another forms. And you have to copy all of `Model files` to make contact form. Let me have a look contact form. 
For instance, AAA is frontname. You can change it as what you want

> First of all, you have to change an action link each contact form like this

```
<form action= "<?php echo $this->getUrl("AAA/index/post"); ?>" id="salesContactForm" method="post" class="scaffold-form">
```

> app/code/local/YOURCOMPANY/AAA/controllers/IndexController.php

```
    public function postAction()
 +    {
 +        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
 +        if ( $post ) {
 +            $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
 +            /* @var $translate Mage_Core_Model_Translate */
 +            $translate->setTranslateInline(false);
 +            try {
 +                $postObject = new Varien_Object();
 +                $postObject->setData($post);
 +
 +                $error = false;
 +
 +                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['name']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
 +                    $error = true;
 +                }
 +
 +                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
 +                    $error = true;
 +                }
 +
 +                if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['email']), 'EmailAddress')) {
 +                    $error = true;
 +                }
 +
 +                if (Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['hideit']), 'NotEmpty')) {
 +                    $error = true;
 +                }
 +
 +                if ($error) {
 +                    throw new Exception();
 +                }
 +                $mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
 +                /* @var $mailTemplate Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template */
 +                $mailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
 +                    ->setReplyTo($post['email'])
 +                    ->sendTransactional(
 +                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_TEMPLATE),
 +                        Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_SENDER),
 +                        'YOUR_EMAIL_ADDRESS',
 +                       //Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT),
 +                        null,
 +                        array('data' => $postObject)
 +                    );
 +
 +                if (!$mailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
 +                    throw new Exception();
 +                }
 +
 +                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
 +
 +                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us.'));
 +                $this->_redirect('contacts');
 +
 +                return;
 +            } catch (Exception $e) {
 +                $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
 +
 +                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later'));
 +                $this->_redirect('contacts');
 +                return;
 +            }
 +
 +        } else {
 +            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
 +        }
 +    }
```

If you want to see full codes, please  visit here
 https://github.com/meezin/Magento1.9_MultipleContactFormToDifferentRecipient/tree/master/app

And if you have any question, let me know and i want to see your codes tho

Comment: Hi thank you, can you tell me how I can change transactional email?

Comment: You can insert your transaction email to `IndexController.php`. Instead of `Mage::getStoreConfig(self::XML_PATH_EMAIL_RECIPIENT)`, replace it `'EMAIL ADDRESS'`

Comment: hey did you test this? it obviously works!

Comment: no because I don't understand very well, I don't need to change the email I need to change the template, that file where we change variables, for example /app/locale/en_US/template/email/contact_form.html

Answer (score 0):

You can set theme in your `config.xml` module something like:

```
<global>
    ...
        <template>
            <email>
                <form_email_email_template translate="label" module="form">
                    <label>contact form</label>
                    <file>contact1.html</file><!--the name of email template,  PATH = app/locale/code_ISO/template/email/contact1.html-->
                    <type>text</type>
                </form_email_email_template>
            </email>
        </template>
    ...
</global>
```

**EDIT:**

If you haven't a module to do that and you want to create another contact form to send it for anther mail address, and maybe you want to customise it on adding the additional fields, you have to follow this [inchoo tuto](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I don't use any module, can you tell me the exact path where I can put your code? Thank you again

Comment: Any module ?, you have well some code ?

Comment: can be add in the magento default contact if I will add config.xml in the app/code/local ?

Comment: No, you can add the layout.xml of the module in local.xml, the config.xml no

Comment: and if I want to add the second contact form? how will look the code?

Comment: Look my update please

Comment: so to use that module and to add this in the config.xml of that module?

Comment: No, let your actual contact form with his one template, then create another contact form with `inchoo tuto` that i sent you, and you will have two contacts form with different templates

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61588/discussion-between-robert-and-prince).

Comment: but if I want the contact form number 3 for example or number 5?

Comment: In this case, you customise it in the module, `controller`, `config.xml`, `new email template`, new `form.phtml`

Comment: I understand this was my question, can you give me an example of code? how I can do this? Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but i haven't time to cutomise it :/ or you create again the same module but change the name and you will have three forms, OR post a new question with the code module

Comment: No is not a solution to have 5 modules there. I don't know how is it for you but my opinion is that will be very ugly ...

Comment: Yes i confirm, it will work but its not a good practice. Please try To open a new post with the module code and ask your question